# Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'Int' in generic

Tags: swift, generics

I've created a simple protocol with a method that takes a generic parameter.

```
protocol NotifyDataSelected: class {
  func notify<T>(data: T, value:T, at indexPath: IndexPath?)
}
```

I've implemented the protocol function as shown below:

```
extension MainButtons: NotifyDataSelected {

  func notify<Int>(data: Int, value: Int, at indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    buttonSelection.updateTag(tag:value, for:indexPath)
  }

}
```

The signature of updateTag is:

```
  func updateTag(tag:Int, for indexPath:IndexPath) {
  }
```

The compiler issues an error that is practically contradictory:
[image]

Why?

This is using Xcode 10 and Swift 4.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
func notify<Int>(data: Int, value: Int, at indexPath: IndexPath?) {
   buttonSelection.updateTag(tag:value, for:indexPath)
}
```

This is not how you implement a method that takes `Int`. That `<Int>` means you have a generic method with a parameter called `Int`. It's not the integer type `Int` but name of the generic parameter, same as `<T>`:

[image]

If you declare a generic method in a protocol you cannot implement just one type, you have to implement all the types.

It's possible you actually want to use a protocol with an associated type and not generics:

```
protocol NotifyDataSelected: class {
    associatedtype T
    func notify(data: T, value:T, at indexPath: IndexPath?)
}

extension MainButtons: NotifyDataSelected {
    typealias T = Int
    func notify(data: Int, value: Int, at indexPath: IndexPath?) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I threw myself off with the <Int> and yes, you're right about my intention: protocol with an associated type. Thanks!